# Determining if an int exist in a list, without using the "in" function

Tags: list, python-3.x

I need to get user input to generate a list of 8 numbers, but when they input a number that is already in the list print and error . Without using the in function to determine if its in the list. Here's what I have so far.

```
def main():
    myList = range(9)
    a= True

    for i in myList:
        while a == True:
            usrNum = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

            if usrNum != myList[i]:
                myList.append(usrNum)

            print(i)



main()
```

Error for above code,

```
Scripts/untitled4.py", line 18, in main
    myList.append(usrNum)

AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: and what's the issue with your code ? why without `in` function?

Comment: how about `myList.__contains__(usrNum)`  ?

Comment: It's homework. Boolean is its own type, try using a = True. Have you looked at the value of your vars in the REPL? What happens when you print myList? Just for starters :)

Comment: Your homework is specifically requiring you to use un-pythonic code?  Seems a bit harsh. I'd drop that class, post haste.

Comment: Unfortunately,its required for my major.

Comment: So can you not do `for val in list:`...?

Comment: @DavidZemens apparently that he can (see cmmts below my answer).

Comment: Please don't modify the code in your question, otherwise the answers made before that will no longer make sense. If you need, you can append new code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be your way of generating `myList`. If you generate it with `myList = [range(9)]` you'll get:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Try using simply:

```
myList = range(9)
```

Also, you need to change `myList.append[usrNum]` with `myList.append(usrNum)` or you'll get a:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

You could also use [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim)'s suggestion instead of the `!=` operator:

```
if myList.__contains__(usrNum):
    myList.append(usrNum)
```

Comment: Unfortunately , I cannot use contains either. Could I do this by a nested for loop?

Comment: You mean you can't use the `in` in `for i in myList`?

Comment: No that I can, I cant use a function like '_contain_ ' or 'in' to directly see if its in the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But you are already not using `in` to check, you are using `!=`. I'm afraid I don't follow your issue now.

Comment: But my code doesn't work with !=  when trying to check. With the changes you suggested, I now get.     line 18, in main myList.append(usrNum)
AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'append'   . Ive changed my original code and error .

Comment: I just run the new code in your question, it compiled fine. Double check your steps please.

Comment: In python3, `range` does what `xrange` did in Py2. It sounds like @halo32008 is uisng python3, and you're using python 2.

Comment: @RoadieRich Thats correct, I should've noted I was in python3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about this:

1. **Loop through the list to check each element.**

   The `in` operator is effectively doing:

   ```
   for each value in the list:
           if the value is what you're looking for
               return True
   if you reach the end of the list:
       return False
   ```

   If you can add that check into your code, you'll have your problem solved.
2. **Use an alternate way of tracking which elements have been added**

   Options include a `dict`, or bits of an `int`.

   For example, create `checks = {}`.  When you add an value to the list, set `checks[usrNum] = True`.  Then `checks.get(usrNum, False)` will return a boolean indicating whether the number already exists.  You can simplify that with a `collections.DefaultDict`, but I suspect that may be more advanced than you're ready for.

The first is probably the result your instructor is after, so I'll give you a simple version to work with and massage to fit your needs.

```py
myList = []
while True:
    usrNum = int(input())
    found = False
    for v in myList:
        if usrNum == v:
            found = True
    if not found:
        myList.append(usrNum)
    else:
        #number was already in the list, panic!
```

Most instructors will be more impressed, and hence award better grades, if you can figure out how to do something like method 2, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, modify as needed (not sure when/if you want to break when the user enters a number that is already in the list, etc.)

This prompts for user input *until* they enter an item that already exists in the list, then it prints a message to the user, and stops execution.

```
def main():
    mylist = range(9)
    while True:
        usrNum = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        if existsinlist(mylist, usrNum):
            print("{} is already in the list {}".format(usrNum, mylist))
            break
        else:
            mylist.append(usrNum)

def existsinlist(lst, itm):
    for i in lst:
        if itm == i:
            return True
    return False
```

Perhaps the point of this homework assignment is to help you understand how an operator like `in` is more efficient to read (and write, and compile) than the explicit loop that I used in the `existsinlist` function.

Not sure if list-comperehension would be allowable in this case, but you also could've done something like this, without relying on the `existsinlist` helper function:

```
def main():
    mylist = range(9)
    while True:
        usrNum = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        if [i for i in mylist if i == usrNum]:
            print("{} is already in the list {}".format(usrNum, mylist))
            break
        else:
            mylist.append(usrNum)
```

In this case, the result of the list-comprehension can be evaluated for truthiness:

- An empty list like `[]` results if no matching value exists, and this will be considered `False`
- A non-empty list will result if at least one matching value exists, and this will be considered `True`

Yet another option which short-circuits and may be preferable:

```
if any(usrNum == i for i in mylist)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, not sure why I was not thinking of using a separate function to do the checking. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not necessary to do it as a separate function, but it's my preference to do it that way for readability (also, anticipating that a function like this might need to be re-used elsewhere)

Comment: I gave another option using list-comprehension (not sure if that's allowable in the context of this assignment, but check it out)

Comment: Your list comp could (should?) be replaced with `any(usrNum == i for i in myList)`, that way you'll short circuit and not check the rest of the list once the value is found.

Comment: Thanks @RoadieRich I'll add that,  too!